# Any way to use base constructor in derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

After using C# for the past decade or two, my C++ has gone a little rusty.

If I have the following:

```
class CBase
{
public:
    CBase(LPCTSTR pszArg1, LPCTSTR pszArg2, LPCTSTR pszArg3);
    virtual ~CBase();

    // Etc...
};

class CDerived : CBase
{
    // Etc...
};
```

It appears I cannot create an instance of `CDerived`.

> no instance of constructor "CDerived::CDerived" matches the argument list

I know I can create a derived constructor explicitly:

```
CDerived::CDerived(LPCTSTR pszArg1, LPCTSTR pszArg2, LPCTSTR pszArg3)
    : CBase(pszArg1, pszArg2, pszArg3)
{
}
```

But that seems like a lot of typing, particularly if I plan to derive many classes from the base class.

The base class still needs those arguments one way or another. Is there a way to not have to rewrite this arguments for every derived class, "exposing" the base constructor perhaps, or must I absolutely always do as I've done above?

Comment: Provide a default constructor?

Comment: @NathanOliver: How does that get the arguments to my base class?

Comment: @JonathanWood: it doesn't.  But a default constructor can pass its own argument values to the base class.

Comment: Doesn't the same problem occur even if it is composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @NickyC: yes, if the encompassed type has a non-default constructor. The encompassing class would need an explicit constructor in order to pass arguments to the encompassed type's constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [inheriting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) (since C++11):

```
class CDerived : public CBase
{
public:
    using CBase::CBase;
    // Etc...
};
```

Then you could

```
LPCTSTR pszArg1;
LPCTSTR pszArg2;
LPCTSTR pszArg3;
CDerived d(pszArg1, pszArg2, pszArg3); // initialize CBase subobject by CBase::CBase(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR LPCTSTR), 
                                       // then default-initialize other members of CDerived
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that in C++11 and later. To inherit a base constructor, you must use the `using` keyword followed by the name of the base class constructor:

```
struct CBase {
    CBase(LPCTSTR pszArg1, LPCTSTR pszArg2, LPCTSTR pszArg3);
    virtual ~CBase();

    // Etc...
};

struct CDerived : CBase {
    // we use the base constructor
    using CBase::CBase;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 and later only, you can use a [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) statement to [inherit the base class's constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors), eg:

```
class CDerived : public CBase
{
public:
    using CBase::CBase;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/z3hlzI)

However, this does not work for constructors in earlier C++ versions (it works for methods, though):

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/s49s5U)

> error: using declaration cannot refer to a constructor

From Bjarne Stroustrup's [C++11 FAQs - Inherited constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting):

> I have said that "Little more than a historical accident **prevents using this to work for a constructor** as well as for an ordinary member function." C++11 provides that facility